# How to use CarrierWave with polymorfic associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

Is it possible to use single polymorfic table for attachments, and different uploaders for each type?

For example, if I have table `company_attachments` with fields company_id, type, image. And what if I want to use different uploaders for types `license` and `portfolio`. Is it possible to do this. And how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just need define your Uploader with your `mount` method. You can use several times the same Uploader Class or another. You can have several `mount` in the same class too.